# How to execute "php server.php" in cpanel?

Tags: php, websocket, cpanel

I have websocket based application which requires to run as ***php server.php***.

In my local Ubuntu computer I run on terminal as ***php server.php***. And it works without a problem unless I break that up with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

So, how can I achive that in live server?
Is there some features in cpanel?

Comment: Connect to your server through ssh and you can do it, like you would in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Either use [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) or you could directly run it by going to the url if possible.

Comment: I assume its a shared hosting server.. If its shared hosting server how we can do that ? do u have any idea ?

Comment: In almost all the cpanels, there is an option of using SSH. You can go through that.

Answer (score 0):

Without jail shell access you can not login that server through SSH. Please contact your server provider and ask them to enable SSH access for your account,

If you want to run that command every day, then I will suggest you please setup cron job through cPanel.